# Excel VBA to get date from textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 textboxes on a worksheet (TBStartDate, TBStopDate). The following code is suppose to pull the date and assign them to variables to use in a search function. The value in TBStartDate is 7/6/2023, The value in TBStopDate is 8/6/2023. When I Dim formattedDateStart & formattedDateStop as a "String" they both return 12/30/1899 and when I Dim them as a "Date" they both return 12:00:00 AM. Both textbox value pass the IsDate () evaluation but fail the error checking. I am Lost, why is this code pulling the excel default date of 12/30/1899 12:00:00 AM?

```
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date

Dim formattedDateStart As String
Dim formattedDateStop As String

If IsDate(Ws7.Shapes("TBStartDate").OLEFormat.Object.Value) Then
    StartDate = DateValue(Ws7.Shapes("TBStartDate").OLEFormat.Object.Value)
    formattedDateStart = Format(StartDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Debug.Print formattedDateStart
Else
    StartDate = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
End If

If IsDate(Ws7.Shapes("TBStopDate").OLEFormat.Object.Value) Then
    EndDate = DateValue(Ws7.Shapes("TBStopDate").OLEFormat.Object.Value)
    formattedDateStop = Format(EndDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Debug.Print formattedDateStop
Else
    EndDate = Date
End If

If StartDate > EndDate Then
    MsgBox "The start date must be before the End Date"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Invalid date format. Please enter dates in the format mm/dd/yyyy.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: `Ws7.Shapes("TBStopDate").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value` there are double `Object`. Your code should throw out `run-time error 438`.

Comment: Are you using `On Error Resume Next` ?  Best not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code I went with and had to do a little more tweeking for want I wanted.

I do want to thank both you though for each giving me a piece of the puzzle.

@taller_ExcelHome - for pointing out the double `object`,  once I turned off the `On Error Resume Next`, I received the `run-time 438 error`. The double `object` fixed it.

@Tim Williams - Once I turned off the `On Error Resume Next` I saw the error. I did decide to turn it back on though so that I could catch all error at the end to call the `MsgBox "Invalid date format. Please enter dates in the format mm/dd/yyyy.", vbExclamation`

```
On Error Resume Next

If Ws7.Shapes("TBStartDate").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value = "" Then
    formattedDateStart = "01/01/1900"
Else
    StartDate = DateValue(Ws7.Shapes("TBStartDate").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value)
        If IsDate(StartDate) Then
            formattedDateStart = Format(StartDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        End If
End If

If Ws7.Shapes("TBStopDate").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value = "" Then
    formattedDateStop = Date
Else
    EndDate = DateValue(Ws7.Shapes("TBStopDate").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value)
        If IsDate(EndDate) Then
            formattedDateStop = Format(EndDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        End If
End If

If formattedDateStart >= formattedDateStop Then
    MsgBox "The start date must be before the End Date"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Invalid date format. Please enter dates in the format mm/dd/yyyy.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
    
On Error GoTo 0
```